# Uploading large file(more than 50Mb) from android to server

Tags: android, file-upload

I want to upload a large file(above 50 Mb) to server from my android device. the method used is shown here, but it throws an out of memory exception if file is above 10 Mb. Can any one help me in correcting this code. If there is any other method , please mention it.

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

```
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    Log.d("pmd", "" + maxBufferSize);
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + path);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("Source File not exist :" + path);
            }
        });

        return 0;

    } else {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Server
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                    sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            // conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024 * 1024);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            // bufferSize = bytesAvailable;
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                // bufferSize = bytesAvailable;
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                dos.flush();

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        tv.setText("Upload Complete");
                        Toast.makeText(Gallery.this,
                                "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }

            // close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(Gallery.this, "MalformedURLException",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(Gallery.this,
                            "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                    "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
}
```

Comment: I imagine it is because you set maxBufferSize to 10MB... But I haven't read all your code. Try `int maxBufferSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024;`

Comment: post stacktrace where exactly the exception is thrown?

Comment: I prefer http method,

Comment: @kmas i tried it, but it also shows some error, it is saying that "Some one is allocating a large buffer" and application force closes

Comment: Is there any method which do not use buffer??