# in android how can i upload large size of file on server by using API?

Tags: android

Hi friends i am making file convert application by use of web API. And for that i need to send my file to server my code is run completely i am able to send file to server but when i choose large size file it show me memory exception the code to upload file is here

```
private String apiCall(String action, List query, String formatOptionXml)
        throws Exception {

    String currentUrl = OnlineConvert.URL;
    String xmlResponse = "";

    Log.d("main", "upload start   ");
    /*
     * if (!"get-queue".equals(action)) {
     * this.getServer(this.targetTypeOptions.get(this.targetType)); }
     */
    try {
        //FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(new File(in.inputpath));
        URL browser = new URL(currentUrl + "/" + action);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) browser.openConnection();
        String params = "queue=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.getMap2XML((Map) query.get(OnlineConvert.QUEUE_COMMAN_PARAMS),"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>",formatOptionXml+ this.getFileMap2XML((Map) query.get(OnlineConvert.QUEUE_FILE_METADATA_PARAMS))),"UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",String.valueOf(params.length()));
        conn.setRequestProperty("connection", "close");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        OutputStream wr = conn.getOutputStream();
        wr.write(params.getBytes());
        wr.flush();
        // Get the response
        int statusCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 400) {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
        } else {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
        }

        xmlResponse = response.toString();

        wr.close();
        in.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.d("main", "MalformedURLException   " + e);
        throw new MalformedURLException(
                "Error downloading pathway overview images :"
                        + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("main", "IOException  " + e);
        throw new IOException("Error In IOException :" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("main", "Exception " + e);
        throw new Exception("Exception :" + e.getMessage());
    }
    Log.d("main", "upload done");
    return xmlResponse;
}
```

by this i am able to upload small size file but when i try to send file more than 10MB it show me memory exception so please help me to solve this problem

Comment: You can do it by multipart. Refer this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026256/how-to-upload-multipart-form-data-and-image-to-server-in-android

Answer (score 1):

I think you can send this using multipart connection request and change your code.

> connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
>   "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

Comment: thank you for your help i am new to android developer can you please explain it more with example ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656169/uploading-large-filemore-than-50mb-from-android-to-server this link works for me